# Problem with dropdown (Selenium + Python)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

URL = https://www.sephora.com/search?keyword=shaving
At the bottom of the page, I'm trying to change from "View 60" to "View All".  The problem is that test case passed successfully, but the browser doesn't change it from "60" to "All".
I'm using this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='css-bpk111']")
dropdown = Select(element)
dropdown.select_by_value("300")
```

I used "mouse over", tried to click on it. Nothing worked.  What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes selenium is just too fast. You can try putting a sleep thread

```
dropdown = Select(element)
time.sleep(2.4)
dropdown.select_by_value("300")
```

Or, you could try to select by index

https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html

**Edited to change C# to python

Comment: This not valid Python code - Thread.Sleep is not part of the language.

Comment: StarKill3r, I used select_by_index, still nothing. I also used time.sleep(10), zero effect.